# How to combine a trim and substitute formula?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Hi I tried my best to combine two formulas into one formula. I wanted to grab all the text after the colon
replace the non-breaking-space. Colon is fixed in every scentence.

1. `=Right(c1,Len(c1)-Find(":",c1))`
2. `=Substitute (D1,char(160),Char(32)))`

But nothing worked, please can you help me find a way around.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You should give more information. Try to edit your post and add more details, a sample data and what you expect as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to:

1. grab all the text after the colon
2. replace the non-breaking-space - char(160) - with a normal space - char(32)

This appears to work. I used a period instead of a colon and I didn't want to return the period nor the space after it (hence `FIND(".",$A$4)-1`). Adjust to your data as necessary.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($A$3,LEN($A$3)-FIND(".",$A$4)-1),CHAR(160),CHAR(32))
```

[image]